Prove that $ \binom{m^2}{m} \frac{m!}{m^{2m}} > 1-e^{-1}$
I am reading a paper. In this paper, there is a part they claimed that
$ \binom{m^2}{m} \frac{m!}{m^{2m}} > 1-e^{-1}$. (https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/gretton12a/gretton12a.pdf, section 3.2)
Although I try simplifying the LHS, I still don't understand why they have that inequality.
Any help is appreciated.

it's a bit weird I agree as the limit of LHS is $e^{-1/2}$ which is about $.606...$ so definitely the inequality doesn;t hold as stated but not sure if that matters for the purposes of the paper cited

note that there is a correction factor $\sqrt {m/(m-1)}$ which is not negligible for small $m$ like $9$ (there it is $1.1..$) which eventually converges to $1$ of course but slower, so lower values of $m$ may hover around $6.3$ but the limit is $.606...$

Is your question about the  lower bound or the claim in the example?  For the purpose of the example, the lower  bound doesn't really matter as long as it is positive, and it is.

@Fnacool My question is related to the lower bound. In fact, I think that to obtain the claim in the example, at least we should have the LHS >0.5 ?

@Fnacool My question is related to the lower bound. In fact, I think that to obtain the claim in the example, at least we should have the LHS >0.5 ?

No. As the authors hinted there is nothing special about $m^2$. You can take $m^k$, for any $k>1$ and by choosing $k$ larger and larger the lower bound can be made arbitrarily close to $1$. With that said, this is a topic for another question.

It's not true for $m \ge 9$.  For example, for $m = 9$ I get
$$ {m^2 \choose m} \frac{m!}{m^{2m}} \approx 0.6307419125 < 1 - e^{-1} \approx
0.6321205588$$

https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume13/gretton12a/gretton12a.pdf
I am reading this paper. At page 731, section 3.2, you may find their claim. Could you please help me with explaining that?

$$A_m=\binom{m^2}{m} \frac{m!}{m^{2m}}=\frac{ \Gamma
   \left(m^2+1\right)}{m^{2 m}\,\Gamma\left(m^2-m+1\right)}$$ Take logarithms, use Stirling approximation and exponentiate again; for large $m$
$$A_m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\,\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{3 m}+\frac{2}{9
   m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right) \Bigg)$$
Using these terms, in the real domain, the inequality does not hold if $m > 8.519$.
If you prefer a simpler approximation, using the simplest Padé approximant
$$A_m \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\,\frac {3m-1}{3m-2}$$ whose error is $\frac{43}{810 \sqrt{e} m^3}$.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\,\frac {3m-1}{3m-2}=1-\frac 1 e \quad \implies \quad  m=8.56732$$

So you mean that the claim in the paper is not always true? :( Do you have any solution for that part?

@Pipnap. I am too weak in the area to answer. But,as written, it is not true. If you plot the lhs and the approximation, you would be surprized. Anyway, nice problem. Cheers :-)

Hello, could you please suggest me some tool so that I can plot the LHS. I am sorry. I am not good at simulation and approximate. Thank you very much ;)

@Pipnap. Give WA the following Plot[{Gamma[1+m^2]/(m^(2*m)* Gamma[1 - m + m^2]),1/Sqrt[E]*(3m-1)/(3m-2)},{m,1,20}]
